# 'kubectl cp' command doesn't copy the target directory but its contents

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
 kubectl cp namespace/podname:/path/target .
```

If I use the instructed command from kubernetes guide, it only copies the contents inside the `target` directory and omits `target` itself.
I don't want to use `mkdir` every time I need to copy.
What's the option?

Comment: `kubectl cp namespace/podname:/path/target ./target` how about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `kubectl cp namespace/podname:/path/target target`. Note specify "./target" will receive a warning: "tar: removing leading '/' from member names". Also, ensure your image have `tar` command or `kubectl cp` can fail.

Answer (score 9):

I have a pod under `default` namespace called `ubuntu-pod` with a file located at root: `/decomission.log` and I got the same error:

```yaml
$ kubectl cp default/ubuntu-pod:/decommission.log decommission.log
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

The solution was to remove the slash and then I was able to copy the file with no message:

```yaml
$ kubectl cp default/ubuntu-pod:decommission.log decommission.log
$ ls
decommission.log
```